# How to make a listview transparent?

Tags: list, text, view, colors, back

I have a listview activity with a bunch of single textview items. Here's my item:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >    
</TextView>
```

As you can see, the text color is white, and the background is transparent. (I tried putting alpha from 0 to 100, it either shows white background or black)

Now in the listview, I have put in an image in the background called "s4":

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/s4">
</ListView>
```

I want to make the listview items sort of translucent such that the background image can be viewed.

Each item should be translucent, the text should be white and visible, and the listview's background should be visible.

I can't seem to get it right, I can put in a solid color, but I want the items to scroll over a fixed background image.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.......... Put your text view with linear layout and set background color for your layout.......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="#F1F1F1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:background="#00000000"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:textStyle="bold" >    
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```